# Loop through PDO statment fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) using a class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have class called posts in a separate file :

```
<?php

class POSTS {
    //Start of class properties:
    private $db_connection;

    public $post_id;
    public $section_id;
    public $user_id;
    public $post_title;
    public $post_details;
    public $post_date;
    public $post_category;
    public $post_display;

    public $num_of_rows;

    public function getRelatedPosts($section_name, $category, $display) {
        $stm = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE section_name!=:Section_name AND category=:Category AND display=:Display ORDER BY id DESC");
        $stm->bindParam(":Section_name", $section_name);
        $stm->bindParam(":Category", $category);
        $stm->bindParam(":Display", $display);
        $stm->execute();

        $this->num_of_rows = $stm->rowCount();
        if ($this->num_of_rows >= 1) {
            $post_data = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $this->post_id = $post_data->id;
            $this->section_id = $post_data->section_id;
            $this->user_id = $post_data->user_id;
            $this->post_title = $post_data->title;
            $this->post_details = $post_data->details;
            $this->post_date = $post_data->date;
            $this->post_category = $post_data->category;
            $this->post_display = $post_data->display;

        }
    }

}

?>
```

Then I want to loop through the results in my Index file:

```
                    $section_name = 'PHP';

                    $display = 'yes';

                    $POSTS->getRelatedPosts($section_name, $category $display);
                    $num_of_rows = $POSTS->num_of_rows;

                     if ($num_of_rows >= 1) {
                        for ($m=1; $m<=$num_of_rows; $m++) {

                            $post_id = $POSTS->post_id;
                            $section_id = $POSTS->section_id;
                            $user_id = $POSTS->user_id;

                            $post_title = $POSTS->post_title;
                            $post_details = $POSTS->post_details;
                            $post_date = $POSTS->post_date;

                        ?>
                        <div id="related_post">
                            <h4><a href=""><?php echo $post_title;?></a></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $post_details;?></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'Sorry no related posts now!';
                    }
```

Unfortunately The results are only one record repeated as many as the $num_of_rows variable equal.
I tried some different ways with fetch methods like:
fetchAll() and others styles but always the result is an error or only one record repeated.

Someone help me with my code please.

Comment: May not be the problem, but as noted in the PHP Manual, `rowCount()` as you have in `$stm->rowCount()` may not be accurate in `SELECT` statements. You will want to do a `COUNT()` instead. *(Example #2: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)*

Comment: Also, you have a `getRelatedPosts()` method but you use a `getSectionPosts()` in your script? What happened to `getRelatedPosts()`?

Comment: rowCount() function is working fine with me in this example, thanks for your advice.

Comment: ^ as I say, it is recommended not using it for `SELECT`, I am merely making you aware in case you did not know it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop, try looping in your method:

```
public function getRelatedPosts($section_name, $category, $display)
{
    $stm = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE section_name!=:Section_name AND category=:Category AND display=:Display ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stm->bindParam(":Section_name", $section_name);
    $stm->bindParam(":Category", $category);
    $stm->bindParam(":Display", $display);
    $stm->execute();

    $this->num_of_rows = $stm->rowCount();
    if ($this->num_of_rows >= 1) {
        while($post_data = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $this->post_id[] = $post_data->id;
            $this->section_id[] = $post_data->section_id;
            $this->user_id[] = $post_data->user_id;
            $this->post_title[] = $post_data->title;
            $this->post_details[] = $post_data->details;
            $this->post_date[] = $post_data->date;
            $this->post_category[] = $post_data->category;
            $this->post_display[] = $post_data->display;
       }
    }
}
```

Your loop would likely be something like:

```
for ($m=1; $m<=$num_of_rows; $m++) {
    $post_id = $POSTS->post_id[$m];
    $section_id = $POSTS->section_id[$m];
    $user_id = $POSTS->user_id[$m];
    $post_title = $POSTS->post_title[$m];
    $post_details = $POSTS->post_details[$m];
    $post_date = $POSTS->post_date[$m];
?>
    <div id="related_post">
        <h4><a href=""><?php echo $post_title;?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $post_details;?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: I just added what the `for` loop would look like, did you try both?

Comment: and this will not repeat my (div) in the index file,

Comment: Also, how many `$num_of_rows` do you get? It should pass more than one if you're saying you have multiple rows.

Comment: yes both of them not working, I wonder that there is something wrong with using OOP and PDO in this way

Comment: I don't doubt that, but when you `echo $num_of_rows;` how may rows (and therefore loops) does it say?

Comment: I have more than 10 rows.

Comment: But if you write `echo $num_of_rows = $POSTS->num_of_rows;` it says `10`?

Comment: Also, you have your `getRelatedPosts()` taking 3 parameters but you only supply 2: `$POSTS->getRelatedPosts($section_name, $display);`

Comment: For sure there are more than 1 row supposed to get out but that not happened

Comment: You have yet to give a concrete answer to this question, does `echo $num_of_rows = $POSTS->num_of_rows;` write `1` or `10` or other?

Comment: In my database supposed I get 10 rows out, By the way after echo out, It said 10.

Comment: Try `print_r($POSTS);` see if the arrays show up in the object.

Comment: Array has come out perfectly but it is the same for all rows, I mean it's repeated :(

Comment: Like there are 10 arrays but they all still contain the same info?

Comment: Yes exactly that what happened.

Answer (score 0):

In my class I should use the following instead of the current one:

```
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I will not get any advantages of my current class properties.
In my **index** file I will loop through the `$results` using `foreach` loop as the following:

```
foreach($results as $post){
  $post_title = $post->title;
  $post_details = $post->details;
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with PDO and I had the same issue with PDO::FETCH_OBJ

I'm using PHP 5.6 in xampp 5.6.30

needless to say that 
- the DB name is animals
- it has three columns only : animal_id, animal_type, animal_name

the following test code works fine and outputs all the records (that in my test DB are only eleven)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals");
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $obj->animal_type . " " . $obj->animal_name . "<br>";
    }
}
```

perhaps you may insert the counters inside the loop or, even better, make the query to properly limit the range.

Anyway, the code above, as expected outputs what follow

```
kookaburra bruce
emu bruce
goanna bruce
dingo bruce
kangaroo bruce
wallaby bruce
wombat bruce
koala bruce
kiwi cambiato
pippo zollo
pippz zoll2
```